# What is {recipientPart} in deleteCaptiveRecipient API call?

Tags: docusignapi

I'm looking at the [REST API docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Accounts/Accounts/deleteCaptiveRecipient/) for the deleteCaptiveRecipient method. The {recipientPart} parameter doesn't have a description in the docs. What does that refer to? I've tried using DocuSign's recipient id for an envelope but that does not work. I am getting a 404 from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out {recipientPart} is looking for whatever part of the recipient object you want to delete. In my case I want to remove the signature so my request was https://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/captive_recipients/signature